# Find matching text in sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, string-comparison

At a charity, volunteers are issued i.d. cards with QR codes. To clock in, a volunteer scans their i.d. card. A script automatically inserts the person's name into column 1 of a Google Sheet and inserts a timestamp into column 2 of the same row, to indicate timeIn. Next, we want to automate clocking out.

When a person's i.d. card is scanned, I know how to insert the person's name into a temporary holding cell. Next, I need code to check whether that person has already signed in (i.e., compare contents of the holding cell to each cell in column 1 until a match or an empty cell is found). If a match is found, then a timestamp should be entered in column 3, in the row where the person signed in, to indicate timeOut. Then, data in the temporary holding cell should be cleared.

I am very new to scripts for google apps, and have not yet figured out how to compare the values in two cells or to code a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can do the following:

1. Retrieve all contents of column 1 with [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns) and [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and push them into an array
2. Verify with [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) either the value in the temporary holding cell matches an entry of the array and if so - retrieve the entry position `index`
3. Use [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) to insert a timestamp into a cell of column 3, row `index`

Here is a sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var startRow=2;
  var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
  var numberRows=lastRow-startRow+1
  var Ids=sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numberRows,1).getValues();
  var temporary=sheet.getRange(2,4).getValue();//please modify according to the position of your temporary cell
  var array=[];
  var timestamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
  for(var i=0;i<numberRows;i++){
    array.push(Ids[i][0]);
  }
  var index=array.indexOf(temporary);
  if(index!=-1){
    sheet.getRange(index+startRow,3).setValue(timestamp);
  }
}
```

You might want to incorporate in a `doGet()` function of a Web App deployment that will run the code automatically when new data is inserted into the temporary cell.

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to give such a complete answer to a novice scripter.